# Running systemctl in Python script

Tags: scripts, python, services

I'm trying to get the status of a few `systemd` services in Python, but I keep getting the error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'systemctl show -p ActiveState --value abc'`

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04, as the user `user`. The `abc.service` file is in `/etc/systemd/system/`, details below:

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 root root 1542 Aug  5 17:31  abc.service
```

The script is

```
import subprocess
status = subprocess.check_output("systemctl show -p ActiveState --value abc")
print(status)
```

However, if I run the `systemctl` command directly, I can get the status `active`. I've tried with `sudo` in the script, and I get the same error.

On a related note, I thought I would have to run the command using `sudo` eventually, but I'm actually running the command as part of my Airflow dag (i.e. not as a separate script where I can do `sudo python3 myscript.py`). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I think this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449250/any-way-to-assign-terminal-output-to-variable-with-python#2449301

Answer (score 1):

I was careless, and did not include `shell=True` in my `subprocess`. Once I added it, it runs successfully.

```
status = subprocess.check_output("systemctl show -p ActiveState --value abc", shell=True)
```